# Images with :nopm: in filename

Tags: android, image, file, google-hangouts

I'v recently discovered that images taken with Google Hangouts sometimes add a :nopm: to the end of the filename. For example, DCIM/Camera/IMG_20141212_123123:nopm:.jpg

This is causing me a ton of parsing issues. One of the biggest being that when I created a File object out of this path, and try file.exists(), I GET A FALSE!!!!!

My end goal for this is that when I run into one of these :nopm: images, I'd like to just rename it on the device and continue my processing as normal.

Here's my code:

```
public static void checkForNopm(File file) {

    final String path = file.getPath();

    if (path.contains(":nopm:")) {
        final File newfile = new File(file.getPath().replace(":nopm:",""));
        file.renameTo(newfile);
    }
}
```

Comment: I remember running into a similar problem when sending out .apk files to testers. If the user downloaded the .apk file more than once, the name would be changed from `foo_bar.apk` to `foo_bar.apk (1)` which would cause android to not recognize it as a valid apk to install. :/

Comment: Why even bother with the nopm just remove the `:`'s all part of "sanitizing"

Comment: Can't do that @Blundell, in order to rename a file, it has to exist as per File.exists, which, returns false in the case of a file that contains a colon in it

Comment: @TheHungryAndroider What are you attempting to do with this file, and how did you get the reference to it? Is your app a file manager? (I mean: there may be other ways to skirt this problem if we had some more context about what you're trying to do).

Comment: Have you tried simply escaping the colons? i.e., `File f = new File(" DCIM/Camera/IMG_20141212_123123\:nopm\:.jpg")`

Comment: @matiash, I'm just trying to get a File object out of the image.

Comment: @JeffMixon, I'll give that a shot but I doubt it will work because of the fact that I can't even parse the uri correctly. I just hope Google fixes the bug in Hangouts and that'll be the end of this!

Answer (score 2):

Read this:

https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/98266/why-is-there-nopm-in-some-photo-file-names

No solution also.  But possibly it is a way for Google Hangout to escape the photo from being managed by other utilities.  I search for :nopm: when I was trying to copy some photo I took when playing Ingress and shared with Google Hangout.  I came to your question, and then that answer in android listed the second.  I believe the answer of "No Photo Manager" is more reasonable than "AM/PM".

If this is really the case, the best method will be manually removing those ":nopm:" before you can manage them by tools.  But at the same time, other tools like "Dropbox" can backup these photos as well.

Comment: Thanks. I actually saw that post before. Like you mentioned, it provides no beneficial insight into any potential solution unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

Its look like 12-hours clock pm/am. The hour in the photo is 12:31:23, and :nopm: can mean no pm (so, am) or that is configured in other type like 24-hour.

Have you tried to check if hour in photos without :nopm: is over 12:00 am?

Comment: I haven't check this, but even if what you're saying is correct, it wouldn't help the situation unfortunately...

Comment: The time has nothing to do with it. Filenames use 24-hour format.